typeorm how to select without null in nested relations
I have tables users , roles , userRoles .
I use Many-to-Many with custom fields and use softdelete.
I have a problem when role is softdelete when i query (example below) user it have userRoles but role null.
const users = await this.userRepository.find({
    relations: {
        userRoles: {
            role: true
        }
    }
})

and my entitys
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    name: string;

    @DeleteDateColumn()
    deletedAt: Date;

    @OneToMany(() => UserRole, userRole => userRole.user)
    userRoles: UserRole[]
}

export class Role {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @DeleteDateColumn()
    deletedAt: Date;

    @OneToMany(() => UserRole, userRole => userRole.role)
    userRoles: UserRole[]
}

export class UserRole {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    @Column()
    roleId: number;

    @Column()
    userId: number;

    @DeleteDateColumn()
    deletedAt: Date;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.userRoles)
    user: User

    @ManyToOne(() => Role, (role) => role.userRoles)
    role: Role
}

If role is softdelete i don't want userRoles.
Is there a better way?
It will return
"users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "userRoles": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "roleId": 1,
                    "userId": 1,
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "role": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

I expect
"users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "userRoles": null    // null or []
        }
    ]

Now i filter userRoles have role not null again.
Is there a better way?
Thank you for your answer,
